# Looping through the array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

First array:

```
var products_cart = [1, 2, 2]; (these are the products_id's)
```

Second array:

```
var cart_details =
[{
product_id: 1,
product_name: 'product love',
category_name: 'love'
},
{
product_id: 2,
product_name: 'product birthday love',
category_name: 'birthday'
}]
```

I want to loop through the elements of the array products_cart and use the product_id from products_cart to render details from cart_details (loop through them I suppose), how is this possible?

EDIT:

I think some of you got me wrong, I basically want this to render something like this:

```
[{
product_id: 1,
product_name: 'product love',
category_name: 'love'
},
{
product_id: 2,
product_name: 'product birthday love',
category_name: 'birthday'
},
{
product_id: 2,
product_name: 'product birthday love',
category_name: 'birthday'
}
]
```

My mistake, I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: there should be 3 results that use the details from cart_details

Comment: There shouldn't be duplicates in `product_cart`!?

Comment: Yes, there should! I want 2 to show twice, not once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the values of the products_cart are product id values, then you can try the following:

```js
var products_cart = [1, 2, 2];

var cart_details = [{
    product_id: 1,
    product_name: 'product love',
    category_name: 'love'
  },
  {
    product_id: 2,
    product_name: 'product birthday love',
    category_name: 'birthday'
  }
]

for (var i=0, max=products_cart.length; i < max; i++) {
  for (var j=0, maxi = cart_details.length; j < maxi; j++) {
  
  if ( products_cart[i] == cart_details[j].product_id) {
       console.log( "product id: " + cart_details[j].product_id);
       console.log("product name: " + cart_details[j].product_name); 
       console.log("category name: " + cart_details[j].category_name,"\n\n");
      }
    
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want it to return 3 results, reread the question again I also edited it.

Comment: @Cedric Okay, I fixed it -- hope this works for you.  It is a pure JavaScript solution.

Comment: @Cedric You're welcome; I'm glad you like my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) while looping through your ids array:

```
let products = [];

products_cart.forEach(id => {
    let product = cart_details.find(detail => detail.product_id === id);

    if (product) {
       products.push(product);
    }
});
```

Comment: @CedricHadjian it definitely does. but i used es6 features, might that be your problem? where do you run your code?

Comment: EJS (express.js app)

Comment: when I logged products, it returned an empty array

Comment: @CedricHadjian Take a look, i used your example arrays from above and the output is the one you are expecting: https://jsfiddle.net/h1qtfjbp/2/ So maybe you have some error in your implementation.

Comment: slevy1's answer worked, check it out. Wanted something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is looping over the `products_cart` with **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**, then checking the keys of `cart_details` with **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**, and looping over them as well. Then you can simply check whether the two match.

You then have a collection of all objects that have a `product_id` that is in your `products_cart`, and are free to do with them as you will.

The following example simply logs the objects back to you:

```js
var products_cart = [1, 2, 2];

var cart_details = [{
    product_id: 1,
    product_name: 'product love',
    category_name: 'love'
  },
  {
    product_id: 2,
    product_name: 'product birthday love',
    category_name: 'birthday'
  },
  {
    product_id: 3,
    product_name: 'NOT IN ARRAY products_cart',
    category_name: 'SHOULD NOT BE SHOWN'
  }
]


products_cart.forEach(function(product) {
  Object.keys(cart_details).forEach(function(key) {
    if (product === cart_details[key].product_id) {
      console.log(cart_details[key]);
    }
  });
});
```

I've also included a third product to demonstrate that only products in `products_cart` will be shown in the conditional.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think you got me wrong, I edited the post, check it out.

Comment: @CedricHadjian - I've updated my answer to log product `2` twice :)

Comment: product_id is not defined :(

Comment: @CedricHadjian -- It is working in the above snippet. Ensure you have copied it exactly, and then build up from there to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: The thing is I'm using express.js, therefore I needed to remove Object.keys(), if I don't remove it it's not returning anything, if I remove it it's returning error (product_id is not defined). I thought this could be solved through simple for loop and there wasn't a need to note that it's an express.js application. :/

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to remove `Object.keys()` for a JavaScript framework... but you could try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-keys

Comment: This might've worked with me but checkout slevy1's answer. That's what I was looking for, but thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var products_cart = [1, 2, 2];
var cart_details = [{
product_id: 1,
product_name: 'product love',
category_name: 'love'
},
{
product_id: 2,
product_name: 'product birthday love',
category_name: 'birthday'
}];

products_cart.forEach(function(id){
  cart_details.forEach(function(detail){
    if(detail.product_id === id){
      console.log(detail);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong, I edited the post, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need list? I think using json instead of list.

```
var products_cart = [1, 2, 2];

var cart_details =[
{
    product_id: 1,
    product_name: 'product love',
    category_name: 'love'
},
{
    product_id: 2,
    product_name: 'product birthday love',
    category_name: 'birthday'
}];

var new_cart_details = {};

// changed list to josn
cart_details.map( item => {
    new_cart_details[item.product_id] = {
        product_name: item.product_name,
        category_name: item.category_name
    }
});

products_cart.map( item => {
    console.log(new_cart_details[item])
});
```

Comment: Yes, I do need a list, I need to loop through the result to show it in the view. This returned 3 separate objects which was what I was looking for but I need them inside an array.

Comment: hmm. then Do you my propose is not solved.

The method I suggested is also not a problem with turning the loop around

Comment: This worked with me but it's a lot longer, @slevy1's solution was simple and straight forward. Thank you for your time!